# Trim space ONLY from start & end of document without touching internal space using perl in shell script

Tags: perl

I'm trying to trim space at the start and end of a document without touching intermediate space in a file using perl inside a bash script

The file has the following format

```
<newline>
<space><newline>
<tab><newline>
<space><tab><newline>
START<newline><newline>
<space>INDENTED<newline><newline>
END<newline>
<space><tab><newline>
<tab><newline>
<space><newline>
<newline>
```

NOTE: `<newline>` is `\n`, `<space>` is   & `<tab>` is `\t`

So the original file looks like

```
  
    
    
START


 INDENTED


END
```

I need the content of the file to be

```
START<newline><newline>
<space>INDENTED<newline><newline>
END
```

i.e final file like this

```
START


 INDENTED


END
```

I tried using both of them the following command, but it trims intermediate space aswell. Both of them trim space & newlines from the whole document rather than just from start the start of the document

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\s*//gs' sample.txt
perl -pi -e 's/\A\s*//gs' sample.txt
```

Both collapsed all internal space

```
START<newline>
INDENTED<newline>
END<newline>
```

I tried this. It collapsed newlines

```
perl -pi -e 's/\s*$//gs' sample.txt
perl -pi -e 's/\s*\Z//gs' sample.txt
```

Both collapsed newlines

```
START<space>INDENTEDEND<newline>
```

Here are my assumptions

1. `\A` matches just the start of the document & `\Z` matches end of document (as opposed `^` & `$`)
2. `s` in the `gs` flag ensures the whole document is treated as single line with newlines replaced with character `\n`

I am new to perl. Appreciate if someone can help me understand where I went wrong

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/1078268/453007

Comment: @choroba After I posted the question here, I was not sure whether it belongs here/in server fault forum. So, I posted the same question there aswell. Do you know which forum is right?

Comment: @mpapec For `perl -i -pe 's/^\s+|\s+$//g' sample.txt`, I get this `STARTINDENTEDEND`

Comment: It might even go to both, but not without interlinking them. No link means people not attending both sites might waste their efforts on a problem already solved elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `perl` in `slurp` mode:

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/^\s+|\R?\K\s+$//g' file
```

**Output:**

```
START

 INDENTED

END
```

**Details:**

- `-0777` Enables slurp mode to make `perl` read full file
- `^\s+` Match 1+ whitespaces at the start of file
- `\R?\K\s+$`: Match a line break followed by 1+ whitespaces at the end. Using `\K` we reset match after `\R` so that ending line break is not removed

Answer (score 2):

Not `perl`, but `ed` is useful for editing files:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' '1,/START/-1d' '/END/+1,$d' w | ed -s sample.txt
$ cat sample.txt
START

 INDENTED

END
```

This **d**eletes everything in the ranges of lines from the first to the line before the one matching `START`, and from the line after `END` to the end of the file, and then **w**rites the changed file back to disk.

---

Or a similar `perl` approach, which only prints lines in the range you want to keep:

```sh
perl -i -ne 'print if /START/../END/' sample.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I like regex & use it every language I code in. `ed` has its own tool specific things (language?/flags) I need to learn about.

Comment: @AshokKoyi That has two regular expressions in it. (Though `ed` uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (And some versions can also use Extended REs), not perl style ones.)

Comment: @AshokKoyi Added a perl one-liner.

Comment: Both regexes can be alternated & be replaced with a single one. Someone else shared this `s/^\s+|(\R)\s+$/$1/g`. Its a nice trick that preserves the last line break

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short sed version:

```
sed -n '/START/,/END/p'
```

or with the negated logic:

```
sed '1,/START/{/START/!d}; /END/,${/END/!d}'
```